# How to add holidays in strftime in r

Tags: r, date, strftime

```
sHour <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2018-01-05 0:00", tz = "UTC"),
     to = as.POSIXct("2018-01-13 23:00", tz = "UTC"),
     by = "hour")
dayWeek <- strftime(sHour, format = "%u")

My_holidays <- as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-06", "2018-01-09"), tz = "UTC")
```

Monday is 1
Sunday is 7
How to add My_holidays in dayWeek as 7?

**Desired output**

```
 > dayWeek
"5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

For each date (hour) in sHour which is also in My_holidays I want to change variable from 1,2,3, etc on variable 7.
So each holiday and Sunday will be 7

**Current output**

```
> dayWeek
"5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "5" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "6" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "7" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"
```

Comment: can you please giva a sample of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
library( dplyr )

df <- data.table( days = sHour ) %>%
  mutate( holiday = ifelse( as.Date(days) %in% as.Date(My_holidays), "yes", "no"))

#                    days holiday
# ...
# 93  2018-01-08 20:00:00      no
# 94  2018-01-08 21:00:00      no
# 95  2018-01-08 22:00:00      no
# 96  2018-01-08 23:00:00      no
# 97  2018-01-09 00:00:00     yes
# 98  2018-01-09 01:00:00     yes
# 99  2018-01-09 02:00:00     yes
# 100 2018-01-09 03:00:00     yes
# 101 2018-01-09 04:00:00     yes
# 102 2018-01-09 05:00:00     yes
# 103 2018-01-09 06:00:00     yes
# 104 2018-01-09 07:00:00     yes
# 105 2018-01-09 08:00:00     yes
# 106 2018-01-09 09:00:00     yes
# 107 2018-01-09 10:00:00     yes
# 108 2018-01-09 11:00:00     yes
# 109 2018-01-09 12:00:00     yes
# 110 2018-01-09 13:00:00     yes
# 111 2018-01-09 14:00:00     yes
# 112 2018-01-09 15:00:00     yes
# 113 2018-01-09 16:00:00     yes
# 114 2018-01-09 17:00:00     yes
# 115 2018-01-09 18:00:00     yes
# 116 2018-01-09 19:00:00     yes
# 117 2018-01-09 20:00:00     yes
# 118 2018-01-09 21:00:00     yes
# 119 2018-01-09 22:00:00     yes
# 120 2018-01-09 23:00:00     yes
# 121 2018-01-10 00:00:00      no
# 122 2018-01-10 01:00:00      no
# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a `join` operations, and several R packages can help. I happen to like `data.table` a lot for this.

#### Create your table

```
R> dt <- data.table(myhour=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2018-01-05 0:00", tz = "UTC"),
+                              to = as.POSIXct("2018-01-13 23:00", tz = "UTC"), 
+                              by = "hour"))
R> dt[, weekday := wday(myhour)]
R> dt[]
                  myhour weekday
  1: 2018-01-05 00:00:00       6
  2: 2018-01-05 01:00:00       6
  3: 2018-01-05 02:00:00       6
  4: 2018-01-05 03:00:00       6
  5: 2018-01-05 04:00:00       6
 ---                            
212: 2018-01-13 19:00:00       7
213: 2018-01-13 20:00:00       7
214: 2018-01-13 21:00:00       7
215: 2018-01-13 22:00:00       7
216: 2018-01-13 23:00:00       7
R>
```

This is essentially what you had, but as a `data.table` using its helper function `wday()` which can work on `Date` or `POSIXt`.

#### Create your holidays

```
R> myholidays <- as.Date(c("2018-01-06", "2018-01-09")) # no UTC conversion
```

About the same, but we keep it as `Date` as they are date objects.

#### Combine

```
R> dt[, isholiday:=FALSE][as.Date(myhour) %in% myholidays, isholiday:=TRUE][]
                  myhour weekday isholiday
  1: 2018-01-05 00:00:00       6     FALSE
  2: 2018-01-05 01:00:00       6     FALSE
  3: 2018-01-05 02:00:00       6     FALSE
  4: 2018-01-05 03:00:00       6     FALSE
  5: 2018-01-05 04:00:00       6     FALSE
 ---                                      
212: 2018-01-13 19:00:00       7     FALSE
213: 2018-01-13 20:00:00       7     FALSE
214: 2018-01-13 21:00:00       7     FALSE
215: 2018-01-13 22:00:00       7     FALSE
216: 2018-01-13 23:00:00       7     FALSE
```

This is the key, and we combine three `data.table` operatons.  First, we create
`isholiday` as a Boolean defaulting to `FALSE`. The we set it for the dates in our holiday vector -- the conversion from `POSIXct` to `Date` happens on the fly.  Lastly we print the result.

#### Check

```
R> head(dt[ isholiday==TRUE, ])
                myhour weekday isholiday
1: 2018-01-06 00:00:00       7      TRUE
2: 2018-01-06 01:00:00       7      TRUE
3: 2018-01-06 02:00:00       7      TRUE
4: 2018-01-06 03:00:00       7      TRUE
5: 2018-01-06 04:00:00       7      TRUE
6: 2018-01-06 05:00:00       7      TRUE
R> summary(dt)
     myhour                       weekday     isholiday      
 Min.   :2018-01-05 00:00:00   Min.   :1.00   Mode :logical  
 1st Qu.:2018-01-07 05:45:00   1st Qu.:3.00   FALSE:168      
 Median :2018-01-09 11:30:00   Median :5.00   TRUE :48       
 Mean   :2018-01-09 11:30:00   Mean   :4.56                  
 3rd Qu.:2018-01-11 17:15:00   3rd Qu.:6.00                  
 Max.   :2018-01-13 23:00:00   Max.   :7.00                  
R>
```

Never hurts to check.  48 entries is what we expected for two days of hourly data.